# What is this trapped-house film?

Tags: story-identification, horror

I vaguely recall a film where a group of people were trapped in a house. In the beginning they awake in a foyer in front of a massive metal door. They try to break through; but the metal holds. In order to open the door they had to go through traps or something?(I don't recall). What I do remember clearly, is that at the end, one person survives and is able to exit the house through the metal door in the beginning. He walks through a foggy courtyard and sees another door. Upon opening that door and entering its room he finds himself in another foyer with other people who have survived their own trapped-houses.

Comment: Hmm... just to confirm does this have fantasy or sci-fi elements? It's not 100% clear from your description.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - What he's describing doesn't seem normal to me.

Comment: ["Movies where the characters are trapped and must escape/solve a puzzle"](https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/hwl8m/movies_where_the_characters_are_trapped_and_must/)

Comment: I've placed this question on hold since there are no obvious sci-fi or fantasy elements in the film you describe. If it ***is*** a sci-fi or fantasy film, please [edit] the question to clarify this and we can reopen it.

Comment: It sounds fantastical to me. Multiple linked murder puzzle-houses  with enormous metal doors and a shared courtyard is not something you'd expect to find in a neighbourhood

Comment: But it could be Saw 2. I’m not sure that’s Sci Fi and it’s not fantasy...

Comment: @Valorum I think this movie is House of 9, if I'm right then is not a sci-fi/fantasy

Comment: @Ram - More specifically the alternate ending of House of 9

Comment: @Ram Thanks, that was the movie I was looking for.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: you're right. I mistakenly posted the question here instead of movies.stackexchange.com (I was sleep deprived). Should this be moved to movies SE, or closed considering Ram answered my question?

Comment: Movies SE doesn't do Story ID anymore. :( But at least you did get your answer.

Comment: Huh, then that would beg the question: What SE does story ids for general movies? (if not scifi or movies?)